# Place beamergotobutton next to title

Tags: beamer, header-footer, hyperlink, button

I'd like to place beamergotobutton in the head of beamer slides, next the to the title. If I just put them inside the title, then this changes the format of the buttons. Any other way of doing this?

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\definecolor{secondcolor}{HTML}{909090}
\setbeamercolor{button}{bg=secondcolor,fg=white}

\title{MWE}
\author{ME}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
  {%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \frame{\titlepage}
  }
  
\begin{frame}{Hello}\hyperlink{bye}{\beamerreturnbutton{Bye}} 
Hi     
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bye}\label{bye}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: From your description it is not clear what do you want, could you be more specific?

Comment: I want the beamerbutton to appear right of "Hello" on the same height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `\begin{frame}{Hello\hyperlink{bye}{\beamerreturnbutton{Bye}}}` I get [image]

The button works fine.

Using `beamer.cls    2022/02/08 v3.66` and
`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3)`

**UPDATE** after follow-up comment

Using this code to get the frame title with red color and small caps does not affect the button.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts} % a font with small caps

\definecolor{secondcolor}{HTML}{909090}
\setbeamercolor{button}{bg=secondcolor,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}% added <<<<<<<<<    
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \expandafter\textsc\expandafter\insertframetitle
}


\title{MWE}
\author{ME}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    {%
        \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
        \frame{\titlepage}
    }
    
    \begin{frame}{Hello\ \hyperlink{bye}{\beamerreturnbutton{Bye}}}
        Hi     
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Hello}\hyperlink{bye}{\beamerreturnbutton{Bye}}
    \Huge \textcolor{green}{Hi}     
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Bye}\label{bye}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Right, in the MWE it works. In my real presentation I have the frame title in red and small caps, and then the button gets affected by this when included within the beamer. But as for this question, that's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

***Is it what You needed?***

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\definecolor{secondcolor}{HTML}{909090}
\setbeamercolor{button}{bg=secondcolor,fg=white}

\title{MWE}
\author{ME}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
  {%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \frame{\titlepage}
  }
  
\begin{frame}{Hello \hyperlink{bye}{\beamergotobutton{SOME TEXT}}}% <----
Hi     
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bye}\label{bye}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```